# Find all the values of a specific field of a layer based on location then select just those values to see where else they appear in the layer

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I have a layer of property ownership in a county and need to see all the property owners in a parish [parish value already defined to feature in the layer] then see what other property those owners in the parish own in the county. I can use QGIS 2.12 or Arc 10.3.1

Comment: I have tried this manually in-putting the values using "Field" IN (Value1 , Value2 ) but I could be looking for over 100 different values and unfortunately the ownership is displayed as a holding number which is 00/000/0000 and I think the / is invalidating the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround that I now use for this problem is to use Select by location and then export the selected to a CSV file in excel. I delete all data except the holding number column then run Remove Duplicates, I add a new column normally of 1s, save and import to GIS program. I now join the CSV to layer using the holding number as the related value. I can now perform a Select by expression on the new joined column for '1'.

It's a long way round but the easiest way I've found to address my initial query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Select by location` from the `Selection` tab in **ArcMap** to select the properties in the Parish, then you can use `Select by Attribute` to select the properties based on your previous selection.

Comment: @PDreyer - This can also be done using the same named tools in QGIS.

Comment: This creates the list of owners in the parish location, I now need to uses these selected field values to select features in the whole layer.

Comment: By using the `current selection` you can select features from the whole layer (by location or by attributes depending on how your data is structured)